# Windows service fails to start, with generic error

Tags: windows, debugging, service, subst

I wrote a trivial NT service using VS2010 and it does install on my XPSP3 dev box just fine, using InstallUtil.  However when I run `net start TestService` I get a generic error:
`The TestService service failed to start due to the following error: 
The system cannot find the path specified.`

This same error is also written to the Event System Log, unfortunately with no more details as to which specified path `net start` didn't like.  So I ran Filemon, but no luck there, none of the output could shed any light on my failing service.

The service runs under the Local Service account.

Any tips for debugging this problem?

**EDIT:** Thanks to all for the tips.  DLLs were fine, catch blocks not kicking in, I had try/catch blocks around `InitializeComponent`, and `OnStart` methods.  The below-mentioned statements of checking the path was the tip-off.  I've made an obvious mistake, I had run `InstallUtil` on my binary from a SUBST'ed drive, which reported success for some reason.  Running `InstallUtil` from a local path fixed my problem, the service now starts correctly.

Comment: Try adding `catch` blocks with logging code.  Also, make sure you aren't missing any DLLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First verify that the service is installed properly using `sc qc TestService`
Verify that this is a full path name (starting with drive letter) and try to run the executable from the command line.

If the above works, I would try to check permissions on the executable file.

Comment: also, service normally does not start from network path. make sure the path is local.

Answer (score 0):

If your ...bin\Release\xxxmyprojxxx.exe happens to be on a network drive (even if mapped to a drive letter), it will NOT start with the  **“System error 2 ... system cannot find the file specified”**

So copy the dir with the exe (which hopefully includes any dependencies) to a **local drive** on the machine (san or internal drive),     **NOT** a mapped network share/drive.